# iOS 8 transparent tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, transparent

I have a UITableView but I don't manage to get it transparent in iOS8, instead it's simply white.

Using View Hierarchy Debugging, I clearly see that it's the tableView that is opaquely white:
[image]

I create the table view in code:

```
    _list = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _list.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _list.opaque = NO;
```

however, the backgroundColor and opaque properties don't seem to have an effect, since the following code results ALSO in a white opaque tableView:

```
    _list = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _list.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //setting to red does have no effect, tableview is still white
    _list.opaque = NO;
```

I figured out that I CAN set the opaque color to something else than white by setting the appearance of UIScrollView first, like so:

```
    [[UIScrollView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    _list = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

so this will result in a RED tableView (independantly of whether or not I will set _list.backgroundColor to something else).

Unfortunately, setting the opaque property on UIScrollView appearance doesn't result in a transparent tableview.. so, the following code also gives me a white opaque tableview:

```
    [[UIScrollView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[UIScrollView appearance] setOpaque:NO];
    _list = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

The problem does not exist in iOS 7 and only appears in iOS8. How can I solve this issue?